# Do not return to main form until complete

Tags: c#

i have 2 forms - When a button is pressed on Form1 it triggers Form 2 to Open. The user has to enter some information and press OK.

If the information is not filled out i throw an error but the result is alwayys returned to the main form - i dont want this to happen until all information is complete. How can i do this ?

Maybe what i should be doing is passing back a bool Success  and handling it that way ?

**Form1**

```
FormSaveChanges FormSaveChanges = new FormSaveChanges();
var result = FormSaveChanges.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // The code comes back here even if not all information was filled out
}
```

**Form 2**

```
private void radButtonSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (radTextBoxReferenceNumber.Text == "")
        {
            RadMessageBox.Show(this, " You must enter a reference number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Error);
            return; // Quit  
        }
        else
        {
            // Save items and return to the main form
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the property [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the second form to DialogResult.None

```
private void radButtonSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (radTextBoxReferenceNumber.Text == "")
        {
           RadMessageBox.Show(this, " You must enter a reference number", ....);

           // Stop the WinForms manager to close this form
           this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
           return; 
        }
        else
        {
            // all ok.... let's return the DialogResult property of the button
            // Do nothing, the WinForms manager gets the DialogResult of this button and
            // assign it to the form closing it....
        }
    }
]
```

In this way the Form2 is not closed and your user could fix the error without retyping everything

The DialogResult property of a form, is usually set to DialogResult.None and changed to the value of the same property present on the button. If the button has the DialogResult = DialogResult.OK then the code exits from the ShowDialog returning the value of DialogResult from the clicked button. 
Setting the form to None prevents the closure of the form when you need to fix input errors

Answer (score 3):

In Form2, when everything is OK, add this line of code:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```